# Loop check classes and swap it JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a loop to check all the classes in a grid.

I have 4 boxes ( blue, orange, brown and yellow ) the blue box is moving right side in the grid and once it goes into a colored box of the grid they should swap with the yellow spot.

I am working only on the orange and yellow at the moment.

So the loop is checking the classes if found it should swap it.

The problem is that The yellow box goes into the orange one but not vice versa.

Any suggestions?

```js
let moveCounter = 0;
let score = 0;
let obs = 10;


document.getElementById('score').textContent = '0';
var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");

for (var i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}

var obstacles = [];

while (obstacles.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
  if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    obstacles.push(randomIndex);

    var drawObstacle = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawObstacle).addClass("ob1")
  }
}

var obstacles = [];

while (obstacles.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
  if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    obstacles.push(randomIndex);

    var drawObstacle = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawObstacle).addClass("ob2")
  }
}
var playerOne = [];
while (playerOne.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
  if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerOne.push(randomIndex);

    var drawPone = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawPone).addClass("p-0")
  }
}

var addPoints = $('#score');


$('#button_right').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;
  $pOne = $('.p-0')
  $pOneNext = $pOne.next();
  $pOne.removeClass('p-0');
  $pOneNext.addClass('p-0');


  if ($(".p-0").hasClass("ob2")) {
  //alert("found")
   selectElementAndCheckClass(".ex_box", "def", "ob1", "ob2")
  }
});

function selectElementAndCheckClass(element, className) {
let arrOfClasses = $(element).attr('class').split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < arrOfClasses.length; i++) {

if (arrOfClasses[i] === className) {

alert('HELP'); //SWAP CLASSES
$('.ex_box').removeClass('def');
$('.ob2').addClass('def');
$('ex_box').addClass('ob2');
$('.ob2').removeClass('ob2');


} else {
alert("not found")
}
}

}
```

```css
#grid-box {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-size: 0;
   position: relative;
 }

 #grid-box>div.square {
   font-size: 1rem;
   vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 10%;
   height: 10%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .ob1 {
   background-color: brown;
 }

 .ob2 {
   background-color: orange;
 }

 .p-0 {
   background-color: blue;
 }

 .move {
   text-align: center;
 }

 .ex_box {
   height: 32px;
   width: 32px;
   border: solid 2px black;
 }

 .def {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="grid-box">
</div>

<div class="move">

  <button id="button_right">right</button><br>

</div>
<div class="ex_box def" id="score">
</div>
```

Comment: *"The problem is that The yellow box goes into the orange one but not vice versa."* How do we make that happen running the snippet? Clicking the only button moves the blue box, not the yellow one.

Comment: Only the blue box can move. Once it gets the orange one the orange and the yellow should swap

Comment: yes, just refresh

Comment: note that you might generate duplicate square ids in your code, especially `parseInt(49 * Math.random())` can generate duplicate ids, better use another approach (eg an incrementing counter) to setup ids for your squares

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that you want to swap color then:

```
$('.ob2').addClass('def');
$('.ob2').removeClass('ob2');
$('.ex_box').addClass('ob2');
$('.ex_box').removeClass('def');
```

Since your `.def` has `yellow` color and `.ob2` has `orange` color.
Logic is let the orange have yellow color then remove the orange from it. Then let the yellow color has orange color then remove the yellow one.

Snippet:

```js
let moveCounter = 0;
let score = 0;
let obs = 10;


document.getElementById('score').textContent = '0';
var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");

for (var i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}

var obstacles = [];

while (obstacles.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
  if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    obstacles.push(randomIndex);

    var drawObstacle = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawObstacle).addClass("ob1")
  }
}

var obstacles = [];

while (obstacles.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
  if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    obstacles.push(randomIndex);

    var drawObstacle = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawObstacle).addClass("ob2")
  }
}
var playerOne = [];
while (playerOne.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
  if (playerOne.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerOne.push(randomIndex);

    var drawPone = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawPone).addClass("p-0")
  }
}

var addPoints = $('#score');


$('#button_right').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;
  $pOne = $('.p-0')
  $pOneNext = $pOne.next();
  $pOne.removeClass('p-0');
  $pOneNext.addClass('p-0');


  if ($(".p-0").hasClass("ob2")) {
  //alert("found")
   selectElementAndCheckClass(".ex_box", "def", "ob1", "ob2")
  }
});

function selectElementAndCheckClass(element, className) {
let arrOfClasses = $(element).attr('class').split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < arrOfClasses.length; i++) {
if (arrOfClasses[i] === className) {

alert('HELP'); //SWAP CLASSES
$('.ob2').addClass('def');
$('.ob2').removeClass('ob2');
$('.ex_box').addClass('ob2');
$('.ex_box').removeClass('def');

} else {
alert("not found")
}
}

}
```

```css
#grid-box {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-size: 0;
   position: relative;
 }

 #grid-box>div.square {
   font-size: 1rem;
   vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 10%;
   height: 10%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .ob1 {
   background-color: brown;
 }

 .ob2 {
   background-color: orange;
 }

 .p-0 {
   background-color: blue;
 }

 .move {
   text-align: center;
 }

 .ex_box {
   height: 32px;
   width: 32px;
   border: solid 2px black;
 }

 .def {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="grid-box">
</div>

<div class="move">

  <button id="button_right">right</button><br>

</div>
<div class="ex_box def" id="score">
</div>
```